# How to implement crop feature in android like iOS does?

Tags: android, crop, android-gallery

I need to move a image within in the rectangle pan in Android like **iOS default photo album**.

Also, Image needs to be Zoom In out Zoom out.

It would be helpful if any suggest idea or help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android library project for cropping images.
You can use below link

1. [Android-crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)
2. [AndroidImageZoomCrop](https://github.com/ozeetee/AndroidImageZoomCrop)

Comment: Thanks. AndroidImageZoomCrop matched my requirement.

Comment: @Rotomac17 Glad to hear .Move Ahead

Comment: Yes. Done. Thanks verymuch. You saved my day.

Comment: @Rotomac17 Its our duty .

Comment: @Rotomac17 Yeah .Same .